# If UK government "ignored the law" on asylum seekers, what are the consequences?

Tags: united-kingdom, law, supreme-court

The UK government wants to send some asylum seekers to Rwanda, but the [proposed policy](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/explainers-61782866) has been [ruled unlawful by the UK Supreme Court](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-67423745).

The Conservative deputy chairman Lee Anderson is [widely reported as saying](https://www.thelondoneconomic.com/politics/lee-anderson-says-govt-should-ignore-the-law-and-start-sending-asylum-seekers-to-rwanda-363162/):

> “My take is we should just put the planes in the air now and send them to Rwanda and show strength.
>
> “It’s time for the Government to show real leadership and send them back, same day. I think we should ignore the law and send them straight back the same day.”

I think it's reasonable to believe that this is just political bluster, but at the same time he is a leadership member of the governing party. Supposing they actually went ahead with this, intentionally breaking the law would usually result in some kind of prosecution.

What would the legal position actually be? Who might be prosecuted, and what crime would they have committed?

(I'm aware that the situation might be so fanciful as to make any speculation completely unbounded; also, I see that the govt intends to try to legislate to enable the policy).

Comment: The court can declare legislation is unlawful but that won't cause anyone to go to jail. A lot of this is technical legal stuff better asked on Law SE: e.g. if the court rules it unlawful, people could probably get court orders staying actions, and if they're broken that would be contempt of court, maybe even false imprisonment, although ministers typically aren't jailed no matter what they do (that would be another question for here). Any answer would be hypothetical on top of hypothetical. But a lot of consequences aren't legal, they're political and diplomatic.

Comment: @StuartF the people in the case linked to _have_ orders quashing the decision. That's essentially what the government was appealing to the supreme court.

Comment: Although this question was first, the other question got better answers, For convenience I've closed this one to point to the other.  Decent question though,

Comment: @JamesK fair enough - yeah, not sure why this got no reaction. Must practice my marketing technique ... :-)

Comment: Unfortunately this question attracted a ChatGPT answer.  That answer was deleted, but It discouraged others from answering.  I don't see anything wrong with the question (in fact I prefer this phrasing)  But there is some thing off-putting about answering a question that already has a long AI generated answer.

Comment: @JamesK wow, ok - I never saw that. Ouch. So, this is the first time that I'm aware of being harmed by an AI. This must be how Sarah Connor felt!